# Bigcommerce Override Forgot Password transactional message

Tags: bigcommerce

Hello I am trying to override the default Forgot password transactional message from bigcommerce to Listrak. My question is there is no way to disable the transactional message for forgot password in  marketing admin portal. Also I am trying to recreate the forgot password link that is sent in the email and I am not sure how to get the "T" in the link.

{storeurl}/login.php?action=change_password&c=42&**t=78739f74e838d8ac391a822d75530f3e**

Comment: Hi Adrian, the T is the token for the customer that is automatically generated via the backend of the BC platform. Currently this is the expected behavior. We do have plans to improve this process for the scope of headless storefronts.

Comment: Thanks, we ended up customizing the forgot password on our end by creating our own setup